# centos6.7,where did the "rpm -qa" command look for data?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

I installed nginx on centos6.7,then I delete all directory or file contains "nginx";but when I use "rpm -qa|grep nginx" command,I can still find the nginx;
when I use "rpm -e nginx",it show no nginx;is anybody could tell me why?

Comment: rpm -e --justdb nginx

Comment: thanks,it solved my problem,but I don't know how to adopt this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily delete nginx entry from the rpm db:

```
rpm -e --justdb nginx
```